# Как по нажатию QPushbutton выбирать цвет для точки paintevent. На данный момент есть кусок кода где цвет выбран по умолчанию

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpainter, paintevent

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.point = event.pos()
    self.update()

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    self.point = event.pos()
    self.update()

def paintEvent(self, event):
    super().paintEvent(event)
    if not self.point:
        return

    qp = QPainter(self.ui4.label.pixmap())
    qp.begin(self)
    self.drawPoints(qp)
    qp.end()

def drawPoints(self, qp):
    pen = QPen()
    pen.setWidth(10)
    color = QColor('red')
    pen.setColor(color)
    qp.setPen(pen)
    qp.drawPoint(QtCore.QPoint(self.point))
```

Мне нужно по нажатию кнопки в моей программе выбрать определенный цвет для точки

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: мне нужно создать кнопки дя изменения цвета точки

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: мне нужно создать кнопки дя изменения цвета точки

Comment: Nigjya_ CHANNEL, если вам действительно будет нужна помощь - предоставите минимально-воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.